# Mac OS : Show custom file size in finder attributes and get info without kernel

Tags: swift, macos, file, filesystems, filesize

Is there any way to show custom file size for file(s) in finder without kernel.

I've few files in a folder and I want to display my own custom file size to all the files. This size would be for display purpose only and original file size will be remain as it is and there should be not any change in other attributes of the file.

Is there any way in programming language for Mac OS X (C/C++/ObjectiveC/Swift) without going to kernel.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? This sounds like a very strange thing to want to do.

Comment: You can’t “fake” the file sizes in Finder.

Comment: Yes, I want to display fake file size in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

The size of a file is a measurement of how much data is in a file, and the Finder displays that value accurately. There is no way to intentionally make it display an incorrect value.

Comment: I'm able to do the same thing in windows but I couldn't find any way in Mac.